# Sonata PixSortableBehaviorBundle and delete

Tags: symfony, sonata

i have a problem with PixSortableBehaviorBundle

i follow this guide https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/cookbook/recipe_sortable_listing.rst

and it works, until i delete an entity...

if i deleted id=7 on sonata admin it happens this on db:

[image]

there are two 5 in position column, how is possible?

my entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
/**
* Partner_Category
*
* @ORM\Table(name="partner_category")
*        @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\Partner_CategoryRepository")
*/
class Partner_Category
{
/**
 * @Gedmo\SortablePosition
 * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
 */
private $position;

/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Partner_Content", mappedBy="Partner_Category")
*/
private $content;


/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="hide_category", type="boolean")
 */
private $hide_category;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="titolo", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $titolo;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sottotitolo", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $sottotitolo;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set titolo
 *
 * @param string $titolo
 * @return Partner_Category
 */
public function setTitolo($titolo)
{
    $this->titolo = $titolo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get titolo
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getTitolo()
{
    return $this->titolo;
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->content = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add content
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Partner_Content $content
 * @return Partner_Category
 */
public function addContent(\AppBundle\Entity\Partner_Content $content)
{
    $this->content[] = $content;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove content
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Partner_Content $content
 */
public function removeContent(\AppBundle\Entity\Partner_Content $content)
{
    $this->content->removeElement($content);
}

/**
 * Get content
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getContent()
{
    return $this->content;
}

/**
 * Set sottotitolo
 *
 * @param string $sottotitolo
 * @return Partner_Category
 */
public function setSottotitolo($sottotitolo)
{
    $this->sottotitolo = $sottotitolo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get sottotitolo
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSottotitolo()
{
    return $this->sottotitolo;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getTitolo() ?: '';
}

/**
 * Set hide_category
 *
 * @param integer $hideCategory
 * @return Partner_Category
 */
public function setHideCategory($hideCategory)
{
    $this->hide_category = $hideCategory;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get hide_category
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getHideCategory()
{
    return $this->hide_category;
}

/**
 * Set position
 *
 * @param integer $position
 * @return Partner_Category
 */
public function setPosition($position)
{
    $this->position = $position;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get position
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPosition()
{
    return $this->position;
}
}
```

my admin

```
// src/AppBundle/Admin/Partner_CategoryAdmin.php
namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class Partner_CategoryAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{

public $last_position = 0;

private $positionService;

protected $datagridValues = array(
    '_page' => 1,
    '_sort_order' => 'ASC',
    '_sort_by' => 'position',
);

public function setPositionService(\Pix\SortableBehaviorBundle\Services\PositionHandler $positionHandler)
{
    $this->positionService = $positionHandler;
}


protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
    ->add('titolo', 'text')
    ->add('sottotitolo', 'text')
    ->add('hide_category', 'checkbox',array('label'=>'Non mostrare titolo in Partner Shop', 'required'=>false ))
    ;       
}

protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper->add('titolo');
}

protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $this->last_position = $this->positionService->getLastPosition($this->getRoot()->getClass());
    $listMapper->addIdentifier('titolo')
     ->add('_action', null, array(
    'actions' => array(
        'move' => array(
            'template' => 'PixSortableBehaviorBundle:Default:_sort.html.twig'
                ),
            )
        )
    );

}
public function toString($object)
{
    return $object->getTitolo(); // shown in the breadcrumb on the create view
}
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    // ...
    $collection->add('move', $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/move/{position}');

}
}
```

my services.yml

```
 admin.category:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\Partner_CategoryAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\Partner_Category, 'PixSortableBehaviorBundle:SortableAdmin']
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: Categorie,group: Partner Shop , icon:'<i class="fa fa-car"></i>'}
    calls:
        - [ setPositionService, ["@pix_sortable_behavior.position"]]
```

thank you for the help

Comment: Maybe you could debug [this file](https://github.com/pix-digital/pixSortableBehaviorBundle/blob/master/Services/PositionORMHandler.php#L31) to see what is happening.

Comment: what do you mean with "debug"?

Comment: Using `var_dump()`, `dump()`, or xdebug remote debugging to figure out what's up… you know…